# Failed to launch react-native app on IOS Simulator iPhone 11.0 IOS13.3

Tags: react-native

Failed to launch the app on simulator, an error was encountered processing the command (domain=FBSOpenApplicationServiceErrorDomain, code=5)

I am trying to run a very simple mobile app with the command "**npx react-native run-ios**" in the following environment setup:

1. Mac OS Catalina version 10.15 on VirtualBox version 6.1
2. react-native version 0.61.5
3. react version 16.9
4. xcode version 11.3

Appreciate for your help if you ever came across the same trouble above!

i have attached the detailed error message for your reference:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iX59T.png)

Comment: try to clean and run your project again

Comment: It does not help by cleaning the project. 
But i find a workaround by installing MacOS High Sierra instead of Catalina.